Best Practices for Securely Storing User Access Token
I'm currently developing a medical health-based system using nextjs for the frontend and Django for the backend. In my application, I'm using React-Redux to store the user access token after successful authentication. However, given the sensitive nature of the data being handled, I want to ensure that the storage of access tokens is secure.

Is storing user access tokens in Redux state considered secure, especially in a medical health-based system?
Are there any best practices or alternative methods for securely storing user access tokens in a React-Redux application?
I'm using Django for the backend, and upon successful authentication, I'm redirecting the user with the access token, which is then stored in session storage. Is this approach secure?
Are there any platform-specific considerations for securely storing access tokens in this environment?


Unless you really need something very specific, I recommend using NextAuth to solve this problem instead of solving it manually. It's simple to use, open source and secure.
You can save the token in session, and get it later by simply calling the hook useSession():

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Component() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  if (status === "authenticated") {
    return <p>Signed in as {session.user.email}</p>
  }

  return <a href="/api/auth/signin">Sign in</a>
}

